# How to add active class to an element using php include file

Tags: php, html, css, include

I have a `sidebar-right.html` file for the sidebar which has the following elements.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="list-group">
     <a href="Sub-Investment.php" class="list-group-item">New investment plan</a>
     <a href="open-creditcard.php?action=credit" class="list-group-item">Apply credit card</a>
     <a href="open-creditcard.php?action=limit" class="list-group-item">Increase credit limit</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I called this page in another file called `open-creditcard.php` 
using `include "..\View\\sidebar-right.html";`

So my final URL for this page will be something like: 
`http://localhost/obis/Controller/open-creditcard.php?action=limit`  or `http://localhost/obis/Controller/open-creditcard.php?action=credit`

I want to add a class `active` to the list-group in the `sidebar-right.html` dynamically using php.

I tried something like this: 
`<a href="open-creditcard.php?action=credit" class="list-group-item" <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/open-creditcard.php?action=credit") echo 'class="list-group-item active"'; ?>>Apply credit card</a>`
But it doesn't work. Is there anything that I miss?? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` doesn't include the query string, but you can use `$_GET['action']` instead:

```
<a href="open-creditcard.php?action=credit" class="list-group-item<?= isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'credit' ? ' active' : '' ?>">Apply credit card</a>
<a href="open-creditcard.php?action=limit" class="list-group-item<?= isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'limit' ? ' active' : '' ?>">Increase credit limit</a>
```

Comment: How do we change the title of the page dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="open-creditcard.php?action=credit" class="list-group-item<?= isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'credit' ? ' active' : '' ?>">Apply credit card</a>
<a href="open-creditcard.php?action=limit" class="list-group-item<?= isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'limit' ? ' active' : '' ?>">Increase credit limit</a>
```